# FogBugz, WebSVN & Cygwin - Diffs Not Being Generated

Tags: php, svn, cygwin, fogbugz, websvn

I can appreciate what I'm about to ask is a bit specific and a small niche but if you could provide some help you might actually let me keep some of my hair!

I originally posted the query over on the [FogBugz technical support page](http://support.fogcreek.com/default.asp?fogbugz.4.29301.4), but haven't had much joy.

Basically I am using webSVN as a repository browser to provider log and diff functionality for FogBugz. WebSVN is allowing me to view logs but not showing any information for diffs. I have gone through the PHP of webSVN with a fine toothed comb and established that where websvn is making a call to the svn utility, to obtain the file contents and format it using sed and enscript, the file ultimately being generated is blank.

I have broken down the utility calls into smaller statements and tested manually using the command line and all seemed to be well until I incorporate the sed statement. Has anyone else had this issue, or know of a resolution? The statement below is being called from within PHP and is the place where the blank file is being generated.

```
""c:\program files\subversion\bin\svn" --non-interactive --config-dir /tmp cat "file:///E:/svn/Users/mwo/test-4.txt"@36 | "c:\cygwin\bin\enscript" --language=html -o - | "c:\cygwin\bin\sed" -n "1,/^<\/PRE.$/,/^ C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\websvn\temp\150.tmp"
```

Answer (score 2):

Hey Guys for anyone stuck with this one I have posted the answer [here](http://support.fogcreek.com/default.asp?fogbugz.4.29301.5) .

Just in case this gets removed from the support forum over at fogbugz,  I basically had to give everyone full access to C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\websvn\Temp\ and all is now well!